# Learning more about using my Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL XTi

Tags: tutorial, canon-400d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Digital Photography Tutorials](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/digital-photography-tutorials)

Hey everyone,

I aquired this camera from my dad, as he got another model, and I have some lenses and the Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL XTi body.

I haven't used the camera much past 'auto' shooting which my non 'auto' shooting buddies always frown on.

7+ years ago in university I took a photography class (develop photos, dark room, etc) and just didn't apply any of that knowledge to my DSLR.

Any site / tutorials specific to this camera? And how I can shed my 'auto' setting photo style? I really want to be more versatile and be able to take better photos, and understand proper aperature / shutter speed, etc.

Thanks, looking for most informative answer to getting started with this particular model.

Comment: Welcome to the form. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/digital-photography-tutorials for your answer.

Comment: Like @Pearsonartphoto mentioned, this is a duplicate. Please don't be offended by this being closed, It is certainly a great question, but, it's better in the long run for all the information to be in one place :).  Please take a look there, and upvote the answers that help you!

Answer (score 1):

Every camera works more or less the same. The most important, you already said it : Aperture, exposure, sensitivity, focus, etc. After you grasped enough of the theory, you may want to go out and try for yourself with your very own camera (whatever it is). Firstly, in aperture priority or time priority mode, you'll have less to care about yet enough to try and learn. Then, in fully manual.