# Taking/Editing personal photos

Tags: digital, photo-editing

I am new to this group. I am just a beginner in photography. I would like to take some personal photographs (especially of kids). Kindly give your suggestions/tips for making it good. Best way of editing, things to consider for taking photos...please forgive my ignorance in this subject.

My camera is a [Canon A620](http://www.dpreview.com/products/canon/compacts/canon_a620).

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question may have the information you are seeking for: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11438/where-to-start-with-photography
Also, take a look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-your-easiest-beginner-tips

Comment: Hi @user5037 and welcome to the site.  We're really a Q&A site with a more targeted focus.  If you have a more specific question, we'd love to help but your question is awfully general.  Can you narrow it down a little bit more for us to help you better?  Check out http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-your-easiest-beginner-tips & http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/baby-and-kids-photos-how-do-i-manage-good-pics  for some general advice and some kid specific advice.

Comment: Also, really no need to apologize for being a beginner or being unfamiliar with a subject. We were all beginners sometime.

Answer (score 3):

To take photos I would suggest putting your camera into the **"Kids and Pets" custom mode**.  This should give you a good basis to shoot kids that are often moving around quickly.  If you want to get more technical you could put the camera into **"Av" or Aperture priority** mode and set the aperture to be the widest value possible such as f/2.8-4.1.  This allows the most light possible into the lens, and will freeze your subject(kids).

Editing comes down to personal preference.  If you are looking for free software to get started with organization and cataloging of photos, **Picasa by Google** is a great choice.  If you are looking to do more advanced manipulation of the photos then Picasa will allow, **Photoshop Elements** is a great option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to try Google Picasa. It's an easy to use photo-organizer that also has some non-destructive editing features. You can crop, rotate, sharped, correct color, saturation, light, apply B & W filters, etc. It's also very easy to upload your images to facebook, flick or make your own photo web site. It's free and easy.