# SLR photography resources

Tags: digital, nikon-d90, learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good resources for a beginning photographer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/what-are-good-resources-for-a-beginning-photographer)

Hi All,

i have got D90 just few days back now i am exploring the features of this but i am new to this field so learn some basic things about photography.
Can any one suggest me good resources to learn some tips or any other pointer in thi regard will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try a [Magic Lantern Guide for the D90](http://www.amazon.com/Magic-Lantern-Guides-Nikon-D90/dp/1600595243)

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of information on the Internet, but it might be difficult to point you in the right direction since you are asking a "broad" question.

In other words: you are not stating what kind of photography you are interested in. Landscapes? People? Animals? Architecture?

My best tips is: Just start by bringing your camera with you and experiment. Bring a photography book along with you and use it for reference when you need it.

The book I have recommended the most to new photographers is Scott Kelby's "Digital Photography". The book is easy to read, and divided in small (usually one page) sections. Each sections describes a technique for a specific case.

When you have tried out some different types of photography, using different techniques, then you'll find it easier to research since you can narrow down your searches.

Comment: thanks for the quick response well i am more inclined towards landscape and nature just drive me crazy.will look for the books and agree about material on internet but for a new person if he is not sure where to start such a lot of material will confuse

Comment: @umesh, please do stick around and ask more specific questions as they come up as you are learning.