# What are good resources for learning how to take photos with a DSLR?

Tags: dslr, camera-basics, tutorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good resources for a beginning photographer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/what-are-good-resources-for-a-beginning-photographer)

We just upgraded to a DSLR (a Canon T2i Rebel) Since I am used to a point-and-shoot, I have no idea what settings mean what and how to use them. What are some good resources for learning how to shoot photos with a DSLR? It would be nice if the articles/books were written specifically for people going from a point-and-shoot to a DSLR.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/what-are-good-resources-for-a-beginning-photographer

Comment: Oops, this question is an exact duplicate. Thanks @Imre!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[John Greengo's course in creativeLIVE](http://www.creativelive.com/courses/digitalphotography) is fantastic for beginners. It will teach you the fundamentals of photography (with bias toward DSLR cameras) - from camera control to image composition. It is long (a few hours of watch) but excellent and thorough.

The same instructor also gave intro courses for specific cameras:

[Canon T2i](http://www.creativelive.com/courses/canon-rebel-t2i-d550-dslr-fast-start)
[Nikon D3100](http://www.creativelive.com/courses/nikon-d3100-dslr-fast-start)
[Canon 60D](http://www.creativelive.com/courses/canon-60d-dslr-fast-start)
[Nikon D7000](http://www.creativelive.com/courses/nikon-d7000-dslr-fast-start)

Comment: Wow! Great resource. Thanks so much. (I didn't accept your answer yet, b/c I am waiting to see if there are other answers)

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with creativeLIVE have a look at their amazing course catalog. Also register and tune up for the FREE broadcast of live courses as they are filmed.