# Best tips for composition and learning composition?

Tags: composition, composition-basics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good books to learn photographic composition from?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/good-books-to-learn-photographic-composition-from)
>   [Can anyone suggest books/resources on the artistic side of photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4804/can-anyone-suggest-books-resources-on-the-artistic-side-of-photography)

http://www.flickr.com/groups/visualstory/discuss/72157628295763237/

This is my solution to a 'tell a story in 5 frames' assignment I got. I was really struggeling with the composition, feeling that there are some hidden, mystic rules I don't understand. I'd be happy for your advice about -

1. Improvments for this specific work
2. A few tips or general guidelines for composition?
3. Directions for where and how to learn composition?

Comment: [tag:composition-basics]

Comment: I think this is too broad. See [the FAQ](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) — _Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much._

Comment: That said, Michael Freeman's blog has a lot of great stuff on composition for storytelling. http://www.michaelfreemanphotography.com/blog/

Comment: Even though the question is rather broad I don't think he deserved a downvote. Someone is a bit too keen on downvoting around here.

Comment: @Roy. It would probably be better if your rephrased your question to ask specific points about each of your images in the series.

Comment: @Imre: ...which is also a duplicate! :D

Comment: This question seems to be less about composition of individual shots so much as a need to understand how to create a narrative using still images. Maybe re-phrase your question if that's what your aiming for. Apart from the last shot the 'composition' doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: Seems like my understanding of this site is similar to my understanding of composition. But I'm learning :). So is it ok for users to post their work and ask for improvment suggestions?

Comment: There's a specifci 'no photo critiques' rule in the FAQ so posting your photo and asking for general advice is a no-no. However posting a photo and asking how to improve a specific technical aspect should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advice I used to improve my eye for composition:

- Forget all rules, learn to be creative (as Ansel Adams once said: There are no rules for good photographs, there are only good photographs. [on wiki quote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ansel_Adams))
- Read different kind of photography books.
- Look at a lot of images

Ansel Adams' quote inspired me the most. At first, I was relying too much on rules or guide lines and got constrained by them.